# Will Reversal badge be awarded on closed questions?

Tags: support, badges

In [How to make money with my programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658378/how-to-make-money-with-my-programming/) I gave a tongue-in-cheek answer to a question I knew was inevitably going to be closed.  After being surprised to find a Populist badge for another answer I had forgotten about, I went back through and cataloged all the badges I have the potential to get.

The question currently has a score of **-5**. If my answer makes it to **+20**, will the gold badge be awarded, even though the question was closed?

Perhaps this is generalizable to *will badges be awarded for triggers on closed questions?*

Comment: @Jed: You're welcome :-)

Comment: @Arthur: Haha, thanks. Just woke up to it!

Comment: It's funny your answer had exactly 19 votes up when I checked it out.  I voted you shortly before 0:00 UTC, so your badge was awarded right after the long list of “Yearling” badges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *will badges be awarded for triggers on closed questions?*

Yes. Closed questions still function like normal questions in all other respects (see the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question-in-stack-overflow-how-do-they-work)).

Comment: Re: your edit, ah, cool -- it's buried in there, I see it now. Thanks. :)

Comment: Actually, I just edited it in, so you wouldn't have seen it if you'd looked there first. :)

Comment: Now I feel less retarded, which is always a good thing. :)

Comment: Like proof by Wikipedia:  "Hey, just look it up on Wikipedia....well, wait a sec before you do, my connection's slow right now."

Comment: Yes, but Jeff Atwood just got the Reversal badge on a closed question, so I think I'm pretty safe here. :P